# Python: Django: How can i find the users Lattitude and Longitude so that i can show the users location?

Tags: python, django

Is there any possibility to find the user's location in django. I mean is there any way to get the latitude and longitude and then the location.

Comment: See [What python libraries can tell me approximate location and timezone given an IP address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543018/what-python-libraries-can-tell-me-approximate-location-and-timezone-given-an-ip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't Believe Django can do that directly, what you can do with Django is request the IP of the user, and the using a free webservice from outside, request the latitude and longitude and then the location

for example... easy python code:

```
IP_URL = "http://api.hostip.info/?ip="
def get_coords(ip):
    url = IP_URL + ip
    respond = None
    try:
        respond = urlib2.urlopen(url).read()
    execept URLError:
        return

    if respond:
        #Parse de returned XML Here, you can use MiniDom
```

By the way api.hostip.info work well if the user is in the USA. Outside not so well... but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Either you get yourself some geo ip table to look up or you use the location library in html5.

Like here : http://html5demos.com/geo

This demo actually shows you a map, but the javascript query actually gives you latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

[IP API](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json) is a very nice way to do it. More accurate than others mentioned here.
[image]